# Boolean SKI logic

Tags: boolean-logic, combinators

I'm trying to *grok* the combinators, so I wrote the basic ones: `K` and `S` in Typescript:

```
const K: Kestrel = a => b => a;
const S: Starling = a => b => c => a(c)(b(c));
```

Then, I followed the Wikipedia article about [SKI Boolean Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus#Boolean_logic):

```
TRUE = K
FALSE = SK
```

therefore:

```
const TRUE: True = K;
const FALSE = S(K);
```

And this is passing the basic tests:

```
const t = () => true;
const f = () => false;

test('Ktf = (TRUE)tf = t', () => {
  const actual = TRUE(t)(f)();
  expect(actual).toBe(K(t)(f)());
  expect(actual).toBe(true);
});

test('SKxy = y', () => {
  expect(S(K)(t)(f)()).toBe(false);
  expect(FALSE(t)(f)()).toBe(false);
});
```

So far so good, but when it comes to `NOT` Wikipedia says:

```
NOT = (FALSE)(TRUE) = (SK)(K)
(TRUE)NOT = TRUE(FALSE)(TRUE) = FALSE
(FALSE)NOT = FALSE(FALSE)(TRUE) = TRUE
```

I wrote a code and the tests and I got:

```
const NOT = S(K)(K);

test('(TRUE)NOT = FALSE', () => {
  expect(TRUE(NOT)(t)(f)()).toBe(false); // <- see these () after (t)(f)?
  expect(TRUE(NOT)(f)(t)()).toBe(true);
});

test('(FALSE)NOT = TRUE', () => {
  expect(FALSE(NOT)(t)(f)).toBe(true); // <- here we don't have these ()
  expect(FALSE(NOT)(f)(t)).toBe(false);
});
```

My question is about the two lines that I highlighted with comments: why to make the tests pass, I need this asymmetry between `TRUE` and `FALSE`? Seems like I followed all the details in `K` and `S` implementation, but in the case of `TRUE(NOT)(t)(f)` I get a function `() => false`, and in the case of `FALSE(NOT)(t)(f)` I get a `false`.

Is there any detail I missed or Wikipedia is not precise enough in definitions?

P.S.:
Here is the code: https://repl.it/repls/FuchsiaFuchsiaTruetype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, 1. your implementation of `NOT` is wrong, and 2. the asymmetry is purely a coincidence.

#### 1. the coincidence:

Note that both `TRUE` and `FALSE` are curry functions that are waiting for two more args to evaluate.

Now check this fact:

```
FALSE(NOT)(t) === t
```

`FALSE` effectively doesn't care about 1st arg, and all it does is to simply return the 2nd arg. So you get `t` as return value, and when you do `FALSE(NOT)(t)(f)`, you're effectively calling `t(f)` where `f` is useless arg, and it yields `true`. Thus the coincidence.

#### 2. implementation of `NOT`

Wikipedia page writes **NOT** as postfix operator, but that's just a literal expression they use to write down the idea. In JS code you cannot write the same.

> (T)NOT = T(F)(T) = F

See that **NOT** is expanded as two args to be passed to the function before it. To implement this idea in JS, you need to write:

```
const NOT = b => b(S(K))(K);
```

and reverse the calling signature back to normal form: `NOT(TRUE)`.

I modified your original code here: https://repl.it/@hackape/KnowledgeableWealthyDowngrade